# Exposing Kafka brokers using Google click to deploy environment

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

I have used the Kafka cluster (with replication) click to deploy container from Google on kubernetes. How do I expose the brokers so I can consume from an external consumer? I'm very new to kunernetes.

I have tried exposing the broker nodes with a load balancer but the external ip given

I opened the port with a firewall rule

But when connecting from my consumer it throws an error about being disconnected

Any help would be great, I can provide more info if asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a load balancer. Kafka clients must talk directly to the brokers.

Firewall is a good step, but you need to ensure each of the brokers are exposed properly via `advertised.listeners` within and outside of the VPC. Refer [blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/).

Alternative, within GKE, you can run [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1/) Operator, which handles Kubernetes resources for you with regard to the Kafka cluster.